# Odd line of pixels under my mouse, only appears on one screen?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, mouse

I do not have much back story or explanation for this. I have about a 20px wide line of pixels under my mouse, and it only appears on one of my monitors.

[image]

Any idea what is causing this?

Comment: Improbable question, but is your monitor a CRT?

Comment: No, three Asus VS239. The line has disappeared now, though I did restart once and it was still there. But after shutting down for the night and starting once more, its gone?..

Comment: It might be the video card or cable. If it comes back, perhaps swap monitors to see if the pixelation stays with the display.